# Nested functions have no access to requirejs callback parameters

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

While migrating to requirejs I have run into a problem that I cannot seem to find the answer to.

The problem is that my nested functions do not have access to the parameters passed to the requirejs callback.

for example:

```
define(['knockout', 'knockoutmapping', 'other'], function(ko, mapping, other) {
  var Something = function() {
     var self = this;

     self.items = ko.observableArray([]);

     self.doSomeStuff = function(data) {
        // I would think I would still be able to access
        // parameters ko, mapping and other
        // trouble is, I cannot.  I only have 
        // a valid 1st parameter, "ko".
        var d = ko.toJSON(self.items()); // this works fine
        self.items(mapping.fromJS(data));// this does not work (undefined)
        // do not have access to "other" either.
     };
  };

  return {
      Something: Something,
  };
});
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.  I know I could put these into variables in the callback, but that doesn't seem like the correct approach to me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Good catch, but this is just sample code to present the problem I am having.  I have matching quotes in the actual code.  Thank you for pointing that out though.  I have fixed it here.

Comment: The issue is not the use of a nested function. `mapping` in the nested function is the same as `mapping` outside. (You could put `console.log` calls to assure you of this, or use a debugger.) If truly `mapping` is not defined, then the problem is elsewhere. Also your description of the error is a bit vague. Please include it verbatim in your question, including the stack trace.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `require` and not `define`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in define, callback is first argument and it have one parameteter require function, try:

```
define(function(require) {
   var knockout = require('knockout');
   var knockoutmapping = require('knockoutmapping');
   var other = require('./other');
   var Something = function() {
     ...
   };

  return {
      Something: Something,
  };
});
```

Comment: Outer variable still lost within the inner function.